# project idea on Java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, project

i am going to build a web based application using Java EE. can you please suggest me some ideas about what to do?

Comment: No we can't suggest you. StackOverflow is programming related Q&A site. When you have specific programming related questions don't hesitate to ask them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best advice I can give from a learning perspective is to find a real problem to solve rather than something fictional. Look round your house, think about your life and what makes you inefficient or frustrated and solve that, or even just begin to solve it. Not only will this give some focus and motivation but you have the chance of coming out of it with the start of something useful to others too.

Don't expect to create the next Google in a week but in my experience, 'play projects' can just be too shallow and simple to learn real world techniques from and tackling something real creates a better learning environment.

Answer (score 0):

Write an application that allows you to enter and update information about all your music.

You can then write navigation through artist and album name etc, and have a search box.

This is hopefully both useful to you, as well as training skills needed by employers.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if you'r doing an assignment or trying to learn enterprise technologies in Java or something else. If it's about the first two cases then you must take a look at Spring, Hibernate, Maven to quickly build something:

1) If you want to do it yourself, take a look at this tutorial series [link text][1]

2) You can also do a quick app using Spring Roo (but if you'r new to the platform, then try doing everything yourself so you could learn something).

[1]: http://www.nabeelalimemon.com/blog/2010/05/spring-3-integrated-with-hibernate-part-a/ Spring, Hibernate, Maven tutorial

Comment: http://www.nabeelalimemon.com has been closed.